Глючит дизайнер в Android Studio
У меня довольно мощный ПК, но дизайнер Android Studio очень сильно глючит. Это выражается в подвисании интерфейса дизайнера. При выборе элемента на экране его свойства открываются через 30-40 секунд. При изменении некоторых свойств через дизайнер просто пропадает фокус или вообще вылетает ошибка IDE (без кода ошибки и названия)
Как можно от этого избавиться? Памяти и мощности процессора хватает точно... И давайте без "пиши руками, не используй дизайнер"

Вот лог ошибки из IDE:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 71 out of bounds for length 71
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.createHierarchyEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.removeAll(Unknown Source)
at com.android.tools.property.panel.api.PropertiesPanel.updatePageVisibility(PropertiesPanel.kt:187)
at com.android.tools.property.panel.api.PropertiesPanel.populateInspector(PropertiesPanel.kt:144)
at com.android.tools.property.panel.api.PropertiesPanel.propertiesGenerated(PropertiesPanel.kt:96)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlPropertiesModel.firePropertiesGenerated(NlPropertiesModel.kt:490)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlPropertiesModel$loadProperties$notifyUI$1.accept(NlPropertiesModel.kt:475)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlPropertiesModel$loadProperties$notifyUI$1.accept(NlPropertiesModel.kt:468)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.NonBlockingReadActionImpl$Submission.lambda$safeTransferToEdt$7(NonBlockingReadActionImpl.java:717)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:229)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:22)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:191)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread$lambda$1(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:184)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWriteIntentReadAction(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:84)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:183)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:836)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:424)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWithImplicitRead(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:122)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWithImplicitRead(ApplicationImpl.java:1162)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:78)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:119)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:41)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:696)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent$lambda$16(IdeEventQueue.kt:590)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWithoutImplicitRead(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:117)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:590)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:73)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:357)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:356)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:843)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:356)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:351)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt$performActivity$runnableWithWIL$1.invoke$lambda$0(IdeEventQueue.kt:1035)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteIntentReadAction.lambda$run$0(WriteIntentReadAction.java:24)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.runWriteIntentReadAction(AnyThreadWriteThreadingSupport.kt:84)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteIntentReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:910)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteIntentReadAction.compute(WriteIntentReadAction.java:55)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteIntentReadAction.run(WriteIntentReadAction.java:23)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt$performActivity$runnableWithWIL$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:1035)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt$performActivity$runnableWithWIL$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:1035)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:1036)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:106)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:1036)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$10(IdeEventQueue.kt:351)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:397)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)


and submit report - вроде очевидный совет.

ну это да само собой) просто толку от этого не знаю

баг-репорт и обновление студии..
